# Code to make multiple api calls (dropbox/zapier)

Tags: javascript, api, dropbox, zapier

I am trying to build the following process in Zapier with the aim of copying files from one dropbox to another:

1. Catch webhook with dropbox folder id (done)
2. Search for a specific dropbox folder (done)
3. Pull a list of files and their dropbox paths in this folder (done)

Now I got some problems in the two steps following:

4. Generate download links for each file in the folder (based on the path generated in step 3)
5. Upload these files to another dropbox account using the download links generated in step 4

The issue is that in Zapier, I can only do one request at a time. So if I have for example 10 files, I need to make 10 separated requests in order to generate download links (step 4) and another 10 separated requests in order to upload those files to the other dropbox account.

I guess I need something like a foreeach loop generating download links for each file and then uploading them to dropbox. Can someone give me a hint how to do this with javascript or python? I am an absolute newbie in terms of coding.

The function should basically do this:

https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_temporary_link for each file located in the folder (I have all paths available)

https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload for each download link generated in the previous step